# Text object updating after StopCoroutine called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerable

I can't seem to track down why this error is occurring..

*MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Text' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.*

It seems to be happening after the StopTimerButton function is called. After that is seems that my RunTimer IEnumerator is still running. Even though I'm calling a StopCoroutine in StopTimerButton() the line ***countdownTextTarget.text = s.ToString();*** in RunTimer is still getting called. Why is that? Needing some help with tracking down the break in logic. Thanks!!

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static CountdownTimer countdownTimerInstance = null; // create singleton
    public Object startingScene;
    public GameObject timeOutWarningDialog;
    public float preCountdownLength;
    public float countdownLength;

    private GameObject timerDialogBoxInstance;
    private GameObject countdownText;
    private Text countdownTextTarget;
    private GameObject canvas;
    private IEnumerator warningCounter;
    private IEnumerator preCounter;
    private Button stopCountButton;
    private float countdownInterval = 1.0f;
    private bool preCountActive;
    private bool warningCountActive;

    void Awake()
    {
        ResetCountStates();

        if (countdownTimerInstance == null)
            countdownTimerInstance = this;
        else if (countdownTimerInstance != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        bool userActive = GameManager.userActive;
        bool onIntroScreen = GameManager.onIntroScreen;

        if (!userActive && !onIntroScreen && !preCountActive)
        {
            StartPreCountTimer(preCountdownLength); 
        }
        else if (userActive && !onIntroScreen && preCountActive)
        {
            StopPreCountTimer();
        }
    }

    void StartPreCountTimer(float length)
    {
        preCountActive = true;
        preCounter = RunTimer(length);
        StartCoroutine(preCounter);
        Debug.Log("PreCount Started");
    }

    void StopPreCountTimer()
    {
        preCountActive = false;
        StopCoroutine(preCounter);
        Debug.Log("PreCount Stopped");
    }

    void WarningDialog(float length)
    {
        preCountActive = false;
        warningCountActive = true;

        canvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas");
        timerDialogBoxInstance = Instantiate(timeOutWarningDialog); // instantiate timeout warning dialog

        if (timerDialogBoxInstance !=null)
        {
            timerDialogBoxInstance.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
            timerDialogBoxInstance.SetActive(true);

            countdownText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CountdownText");
            countdownTextTarget = countdownText.GetComponent<Text>();

            stopCountButton = timerDialogBoxInstance.GetComponentInChildren<Button>(); // get reference to keep playing button
            stopCountButton.onClick.AddListener(StopTimerButton); // add button listener
        }

        if (warningCountActive && !preCountActive)
        {
            warningCounter = RunTimer(length); // create new reference to counter, resets countdown to countdownLength
            StartCoroutine(warningCounter);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RunTimer(float seconds)
    {
        // PRECOUNT TIMER
        if (!warningCountActive)
        {
            float s = seconds;
            while (s > 0)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(countdownInterval);
                s -= countdownInterval;
                Debug.Log("PreCount: " + s);
            }

            if (s == 0)
            {
                preCountActive = false;
                warningCountActive = true;
                WarningDialog(countdownLength);
            }
        }

        // WARNING DIALOG TIMER
        if (!preCountActive && warningCountActive)
        {
            float s = seconds;
            while (s > 0)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(countdownInterval);
                countdownTextTarget.text = s.ToString();
                s -= countdownInterval;
                Debug.Log("WarningCountdown: " + s);
            }

            if (s == 0)
            {
                StopCoroutine(warningCounter);

                if (timerDialogBoxInstance)
                    Destroy(timerDialogBoxInstance);

                RestartGame();
            }
        }
    }

    void StopTimerButton()
    {
        warningCountActive = false;
        StopCoroutine(warningCounter);

        if (timerDialogBoxInstance)
        {    
            Destroy(timerDialogBoxInstance);
        }
        Debug.Log("Restart Cancelled");
    }

    void ResetCountStates()
    {
        preCountActive = false;
        warningCountActive = false;
    }

    void RestartGame()
    {
        ResetCountStates();
        SceneManager.LoadScene(startingScene.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `CountdownText` a child of `timerDialogBoxInstance`?

Comment: yes, it is a child of timerDialogBoxInstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Destroy(timerDialogBoxInstance);` that also destroys `countdownText` and `countdownTextTarget` (which you do inside `StopTimerButton()` and `RunTimer()`).

You should check inside `RunTimer()` (before accessing the Text object) to see if the object has been destroyed and if so, exit early.

You might also want to set the variables to null after destroying their parent transform.

Comment: Also, instead of `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CountdownText");` you can use `timerDialogBoxInstance.GetChild(int)` or `timerDialogBoxInstance.FindChild(string)` which is faster.